# Review Page With Computation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, qualtrics

I have an input text that needs to fill in a Quantity and it prints out to the next page the result of that value times 100. 
Please see screenshot below:

Could you please simple code how it works in Qualtrics using its javascript API?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript. You can pipe an expression on the review page where you want the number to display:

```
$e{ q://QID1/ChoiceTextEntryValue * 100 }
```